# How can I transfer my custom domain from Network Solutions to Azure?

Tags: azure, dns, transfer

I have a domain registered at Network Solutions and I would like to transfer it to Azure. Please guide me with the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible.
If you buy a domain in azure it is via GoDaddy. 
You could try contacting the azure support to see if they have a manual way of doing this. But the latest I saw you can only manage domains bought in the portal.

Answer (score 1):

You may not transfer it to Azure, because the Azure is not a domain registrar. Instead of transferring, you can use Network Solutions and bind your domain without any transfer. You could try to transfer it to GoDaddy which is being used as a domain registrar for purchasing the domains for Azure Web Apps, but it will involve an extra step. 
The binding should be done on Azure portal and on the registrar (Network Solutions) portal:

1) You need to edit DNS Zone file on the Network Solutions site. You may follow [that link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/). Basically, you need to add CNAME for your domain that will be set for your Azure Web Site name (site.azurewebsites.net, can be found on the Azure Web App dashboard). That is the string you need to add:

```
"www" : "site.azurewebsites.net".
```

2) Go to the Azure Web App portal and Domains pane in the settings. Add your custom domain.

If you need A type, then refer to the link above again. And, after setting this up, give a little time to propagate the DNS.

Comment: This is not the question of the poster.

Comment: Why? There is no such process of "transferring" the domain name to Azure, because Azure is not a domain registrar. It can be transferred to GoDaddy, but the process will not change.

Comment: The question was how he could transfer the domain. 
As you said it is not possible seeing the domains are handled by GoDaddy (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you cannot transfer the domain registration to Azure, since Azure is not a domain registrar.

However, you can host the DNS zone in the Azure DNS service, and use Azure DNS to manage your DNS records.  The domain registration and renewal would remain with Network Solutions, but all DNS management would happen in Azure.

To do this, you should create a DNS zone with the correct domain name in the Azure DNS service (you can do this via the Azure portal).  Then use the Network Solutions site to delegate the domain to the name servers assigned to your DNS zone in Azure (the name servers are shown in the Azure Portal).